# want to check the value of the input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new to js i wanted to check the entered number of amount in input type "number"

```
  <input type="number" id="val" value="1" class="input-text" >
```

I was trying

```
  $("input: number").focus(function(){
   var val = $("#val").val();
   alert("there are", val + "in your cart");
 });
```

i don't know how to get value from form fields with jquery i just wanted to display the number entered in number field

Here is an fiddle example  https://jsfiddle.net/s81g6963/

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/s81g6963/1/

Comment: Looks fine, expect that I do not understand why you listen to the `focus` event. That event is raise _before_ you can input anything per definition. have a try using the `focusout` or `blur` event instead.

Comment: i was trying on .ready function also but its not returning any result as you can see i've set the value = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the below code. When the document is ready you can get input field value. For more info check my jsfiddle link. **Note: you can use blur event instead of focus.**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var get_val = $("#val").val();
alert("there are " + get_val + " in your cart");
        $("#val").blur(function(){
        var get_val = $(this).val();
        alert("there are " + get_val + " in your cart");
        });

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vetri/Lpewocp3/)

Comment: And if in Input to write Here so 1e + 24.?Everything will work and I do not think it is right.